# Does IEEE int->float conversion commute with + and *?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Suppose that TOFLOAT represents the operation of converting/coercing a value having some integer type INT to one having some (range-compatible[1]) floating point type FLOAT, according to the IEEE standards.  Does this operation commute with addition and multiplication?  In other words, if x and y are arbitrary values of type INT, does the IEEE standard guarantee that the following equalities will always evaluate to true?:

```
  TOFLOAT(x) + TOFLOAT(y) == TOFLOAT(x+y)
  TOFLOAT(x) * TOFLOAT(y) == TOFLOAT(x*y)
```

Thanks!

~kj

[1] by "range-compatible" I mean that the every value of type INT fits within the range of values representable as type FLOAT; this qualification is probably unnecessary for IEEE types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, neither of these holds.  For a simple counterexample for the first one, with a 64-bit (signed or unsigned) integer type, and the usual binary64 IEEE double precision type, consider the case where `x = 2**53 + 1` and `y = 2`.  Then under the IEEE 754 rules, assuming the usual default rounding mode of round-half-to-even, `TOFLOAT(x) + TOFLOAT(y)` will be `2**53 + 2`, while `TOFLOAT(x + y)` will be `2**53 + 4`.  Counterexamples for the multiplication case should be equally easy to find.

---

EDIT:  For the multiplication, a counterexample is given by `x = 2**53 + 1` and `y = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

I think both hold, provided the operations do not overflow and you are converting eg. 32-bit integers into double precision IEEE. I could be wrong however, since I don't have the IEEE standard at my disposal.

Indeed, 32-bit integers are exactly representable in double precision IEEE 754 floating point numbers and arithmetic operations are guaranteed to be exact within 1 ULP. Since you have (strictly) more than 32 bit mantissa precision, this should hold.

Comment: As Mark Dickinson showed, the identities don't hold even when the integer operations don't overflow, although the examples he showed can be construed as overflow of sorts...  Thanks.

Comment: @kjo: he takes an example where there are fewer bits in the mantissa than in the integer type. I of course rule out this case.